# Problems with onResume()

Tags: android

I am developing the typical RSS application. In the method onCreate define the layout to paint the screen and in the method onResume do a query to a URL to extract the data. Should paint the screen and then check the URL, right? because I do not paint the screen until the request to the URL has been answered.

How do I get paint the screen and before refer to the URL?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to query a URL to retrieve some data, then this should be done in either an `AsyncTask` or a new `Thread`/`Handler` combination.  If you load the URL in `onResume` then the data load is happening in the UI thread, which can block user interaction and cause your app to be killed by the OS.

- [Docs for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [AsyncTask example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html)
- [Thread example](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#threading)

Comment: Good! AsyncTask has been a perfect solution :)

Comment: If the answer helped you, click the ✔ to the left to accept it. People here will like you more if you do that (on all your questions).